# how to print a timestamp in a certain format using java.Time

Tags: java, localization

I need to print a timestamp using `java.Time` for a locale given as something like `en_US`:

```
Printed on 03/13/2019 at 20:04:03 (GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta.
```

Comment: Please improve the description and search for similar problems. It looks like a common problem (with solutions published).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code responds to your requirement.
You can copy/paste the code from the `//When`section below.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import static java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse;

public class FormatDateTest {


    /**
     *  i need to print above using java.Time from country code like "en_US".
     *  Printed on 03/13/2019 at 20:04:03 (GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta.
     **/
    @Test
    public void format_shouldReturn() {
        // Given
        ZonedDateTime nowInUSA = parse("2019-03-13T09:04:03-05:00[America/New_York]");

        //When
        ZonedDateTime nowInGmtPlus7 = nowInUSA.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.ofOffset("GMT", ZoneOffset.of("+7")));
        String formattedDate = nowInGmtPlus7.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        String formattedTime = nowInGmtPlus7.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss (z)"));
        String message = String.format("Printed on %s at %s Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta.", formattedDate, formattedTime);

        //Then
        Assert.assertEquals("Printed on 03/13/2019 at 20:04:03 (GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta.",
                message);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need to generate this data for different country using locale

Comment: you're welcome @vaibhavpatil. Locale and TimeZone are not necessarily related 1:1. You'll have to maintain a locale->timezone mapping table by yourself.